# Background color of parent-div from left side of screen to right edge of text

Tags: css, css-position, tailwind-css

I'm trying to accomplish something like this:

[image]

The heading text has a max width of 64rem and it's parent div is horizontally centered with margin-right and -left set to auto.

The paragraph text below is a bit more narrow and has a max-width of 56rem and is also horizontally centered.

Setting the text like this works fine. My problem is, that I don't know how to set the parent-div which wraps around those two texts. The div has a background color and it should go from the left side of the screen to the right edge of the paragraph text.

My code looks like this:

```css
.parent-div {
    background-color: #907272;
    ???
}
 
 .heading-div {
    max-width: 64rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
  
.paragraph-div {
    max-width: 56rem;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent-div'>
    <div class='heading-div'>
      <h2>This is a heading.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class='paragraph-div'>
      <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor...</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Important note: I am working with tailwindcss classes. I wrote the sample code in plain css for better understanding.

My main question is: How do I set the parent-div, that it goes from the left side of the screen to the right edge of the paragraph text?

Comment: Perhaps you can apply a solution similar to https://css-tricks.com/full-width-containers-limited-width-parents/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider a gradient coloration to avoid messing with other stuff:

```css
.parent-div {
  overflow: auto;
  background:
   linear-gradient(-90deg,
   #0000 calc(50vw - 56rem/2),
   #907272 0); 
}

.heading-div {
  max-width: 64rem;
  margin: auto;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}

.paragraph-div {
  max-width: 56rem;
  margin: auto;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent-div'>
  <div class='heading-div'>
    <h2>This is a heading.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class='paragraph-div'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another solution is to apply the coloration to the paragraph element

```css
.parent-div {
  overflow: auto;
}

.heading-div {
  max-width: 64rem;
  margin: auto;
  outline: 1px solid green;
}

.paragraph-div {
  max-width: 56rem;
  margin: auto;
  outline: 1px solid red;
  border-image: conic-gradient(#907272 0 0) fill 0//100vh 0 20px 100vw;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent-div'>
  <div class='heading-div'>
    <h2>This is a heading.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class='paragraph-div'>
    <p>Lorem ipsum sit dolor...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the border image trick is not intuitive. I have an article that will get published soon to explain it. I will add the link when it's live.